# PHP Module already loaded warning

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu, php-7.1

I am getting this error 
`PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0` if I try to run and PHP commands on my VPS. I am only running the extension=xml.so on my php7.1 install.

Any ideas?